# iOS Location Picker

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

[image]I want a location picker like iPhone Flava application on appstore. In fact it has an image on top of it which has a center to the center of iPhone screen. User scrolls the map and whenever add location button is pressed, the current center point will be added as location. See attached image. Can anyone tell me how can i get this???

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the crosshair: layer a view with your own art on top of the `MKMapView`.

For the center, see `MKMapView`'s property [`centerCoordinate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW48).

To make an annotation on the map from that coordinate, read up on [Annotating the Map](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW26) in Apple's documentation.